# Sharepoint infopath - cascading list

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, designer

So I'm creating a list via infopath. The required columns are:
1. Vaccine options (vaccine a, b, c...n)
2. Prices of the vaccine
3. Quantity
4. Total

I need to create a list wherein if i choose vaccine a, column 2 will be auto populated by the price. Also, i need to derive the total cost (qty x price). How can i do these without java script/ codes? Thanks!

Comment: The price varies per vaccine type

Answer (score 0):

In your infopath you need to add an secondary data source. It will be a price list, in filter options for secondary data source you need to use the Vaccine Options to filter out the results and use it to populate the price field (do not load the data source on form load only after the Vaccine Options have changed, you can use a rule for that). Then you can calculate your total either in Infopath or use calculated column in SharePoint (with latter option the value Total value will change only after submitting the IP form.